# how to detect browser, os and source using user_agent

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, user-agent

When i printed

```
request.user_agent
```

its giving:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36
```

I need a way to separate browser, os, devise from the above answer and store the in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at one of the many excellent [gems in this space](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/User_Agent_Detection)

Comment: Ok, is there any other gem to help me out

Comment: Well there were 6 on the page I linked you to :)

Comment: Your answer really helped me a lot. Now I am facing some strange issue which was described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65734721/access-to-xmlhttprequest-was-blocked . I was posted that question a long ago, but I didn't get any suggestion. I just recalled my questions and seeking help from the people who helped me in solving my previous questions.